# Is it a to merge dev into release-branch prior to merging release-branch back to dev?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging, git-flow

We're using something a kin to git flow at my place. It's soon time to merge our release branch back into dev. My plan is to create a pull request to merge our release-branch back into dev so that the rest of our dev team gets a chance, to view the changes in bitbucket.

In order to resolve any potential conflicts in our release branch prior to creating the PR, I merged dev back into our release branch. But now I'm told that this might be a bad idea. Put simply: **is it bad practice or "dangerous" to merge dev back into a release-branch?**

I've been told to do this with my feature-branches before creating a PR, and I figured that this should also apply to this release branch.

**Note**, I also did this merge by first merging into an ongoing bugfix-branch I had. So the flow was like this:

1. I created my branch *bugfixes-1* from our ongoing *release-branch* (which in turned was created from dev of course, way back)
2. I committed some fixes, then I merged *dev* into my *bugfix-branch*
3. Then I also merged the *release branch* into my *bugfix branch* in case my other colleague had made any changes
4. Then I created a pull request to merge my *bugfix-branch* (including everything that was merged from dev) into our *release-branch*.
5. The PR was accepted. But now I'm being told that maybe this wasn't such a good idea.

Note that I have not yet merged anything back to dev.So if I need to resolve or revert something in our release-branch, I can still do this without messing up dev.

Is this something that is likely to mess up the history or something? Why would this be a bad idea? Are there any problems we're likely to run into now that we merge our release-branch back to dev eventually?

Thank you so much for the help. I'm sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I simply couldn't find any good answers anywhere.

EDIT:
One thing worth mentioning is that our repository is divided into two folders: "Product1, Product2". Our changes in our release branch made almost exclusively in Product1, whereas the changes made in by the rest of the team (dev) are almost exclusively in the folder Product2. So if we have to manually move our changes to dev or something, that should be fairly easy, but we'd lose the history which would be unfortunate.

Comment: How exactly are you using your branches? Assuming `release` is a branch that could be used to deploy to production at a moment's notice, I would *not* be merging anything from `dev` into `release` without first verifying the combination. Merging `release` into `dev` is a good *first* step towards verifying that the combination of the two works.

Comment: Thanks for your response! You bring up a good point, but no this is not an issue for us. The stuff we're adding from dev is not gonna effect our product, except in some cases where it effects changed config files in which case the changes are desired. Also, right now it doesn't look like we'll ever release directly from this "release"-branch, which is stupid I know. But it will be merged back into dev.

Comment: And I'll add that I'm not much concerned about releasing from this release branch. I'm really only concerned about potentially messing up the history somehow by first merging changes into my release branch and then merging the release branch back into dev - like it'll overwrite the history for those merged commits or something. Needless to say, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Branch names are not part of the history. It's distributed VCS, so your local branch names is only your concern. You could do whatever is convenient for you.

The only concern is you should understand what you are doing and don't be confused by bad choice of naming, so you do less mistakes while creating pull requests or pushing directly to public repositories.